# Ionic/Angular navigation after firebase auth

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, navigation, router

After I sign in with firebase google sign in method, I want to navigate to home page.
I can't figure out, why the navigation is not working.
Here is my code:

```
async signInWithGoogle() {

 // authentication works:
 await this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());

 // but the following code doesn't get executed:
 this.ngZone.run(() => {
  this.router.navigate(['tabs/home']);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For navigation you should use one of these methods:

```
this.router.navigate(['tabs', 'home']);
```

or

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried all different ways for navigation. But I have found that any code below this line will not execute. the problem seems to be somewhere else.
With this code, i expect all the following lines to be executed once the asynchronous operation is complete. But this does not seem to be the case. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: @Milchgraf Probably `this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect` fails. Try to wrap it in `try/catch`.

Comment: I already tried this. `this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect` or `this.afAuth.signInWithPopup` works perfectly fine. 
I also tried to chain ".then" to this method `this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then()`

Comment: @Milchgraf Does navigation works if you remove/comment `this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect` line? Did you check the call inside `run()`? Is it calls? Have you any guards for navigation? And try to navigate without `ngZone.run()`

Comment: Yes, I have an guard on /tabs/home. When I use `this.afAuth.signInWithPopup` the code inside run() gets excecuted, but the navigation doesn't work. I think its because of the guard on /tabs/home. 

When I use `this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect` I have to check the redirect result via `this.afAuth.getRedirectResult()`. This method has to run in `ngOnInit()` on the login page. But navigation only works if I turn off the guard on /tabs/home.

Comment: @Milchgraf If you still have problems add your navigation guard code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

My guard looks like:

```
canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('welcome');
    }

    return this.authService.isLoggedIn;
}
```

and the `isLoggedIn` getter looks like:

```
get isLoggedIn() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
}
```

my guess is that the return value is false because the rest works asynchron

I added a getAuthState method to the authService which returns a boolean to, but asynchron:

```
async getAuthState() {
    const result = await this.afAuth.getRedirectResult();
    if (result.user) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

And updated the guard to look like this:

```
canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('welcome');
    } else {
      return this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    }

    if (!this.authService.getAuthState()) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('welcome');
    }
    return this.authService.getAuthState();
}
```

and in the login page I added:

```
this.authService.getAuthState().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result) {
      console.log('should redirect');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home');
    }
});
```

the console logging is `true` and `should redirect` but its not redirecting to /tabs/home.

Maybe I have to do a little research..
[Here I found a similar issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/266)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for the auth-guard [here](https://jsmobiledev.com/article/angular-guard)

Login-Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.getAuthState().then(result => {
    if (result) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home');
    }
  });

  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/home');
  }
}
```

Auth-Guard:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User) => {
    if (user) {
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/welcome']);
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
});
```

And in the auth service I only execute the login and make an auth-check for the redirect result:

```
async signInWithGoogle() {
  await this.afAuth
 .signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

async getAuthState() {
  const result = await this.afAuth.getRedirectResult();
  if (result.user) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```